# What is a Trimpar Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Trimpar Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| TRIMPAR Words™ | Not TRIMPAR Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| PHANTOM | ADJUSTS |
| LIKABLE | OFFHAND |
| LEGIBLE | AUDITOR |
| UTILIZE | ECHELON |
| QUELLED | ALLUDES |
| TACITLY | UNBLIND |
| LIMITED | TEXTUAL |
| UNWEAVE | REVIVED |
| REQUIRE | OUTLAYS |
| ANSWERS | IMPOSES |
| PROVIDE | CONVEYS |
| ELUSORY | PARTAKE |

The CSV version:

```
TRIMPAR Words™,Not TRIMPAR Words™
PHANTOM,ADJUSTS
LIKABLE,OFFHAND
LEGIBLE,AUDITOR
UTILIZE,ECHELON
QUELLED,ALLUDES
TACITLY,UNBLIND
LIMITED,TEXTUAL
UNWEAVE,REVIVED
REQUIRE,OUTLAYS
ANSWERS,IMPOSES
PROVIDE,CONVEYS
ELUSORY,PARTAKE
```

These are not the only examples of Trimpar Words™, many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

---

HINT:

> "Trimpar" is relevant :)

HINT 2:

> you may just agree
>  just see it in three
>  if you can't see the truth
>  just take it in two

Comment: ahh I see you decided to take a crack at this style of question too eh? How about another hint since it's been over a month?

Comment: Does the fact that they are all seven-letter words mean anything?

Comment: It's been some time, so I will add another hint. Hint added, have fun!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Trimpar Word is a word where:

> The **third letter** is represented by an **odd number** in A1Z26 (i.e. it is a letter with an odd-numbered position in the English alphabet).

Note that:

> The 24 Trimpar Words and exceptions appear to have been carefully chosen by the OP so that every letter between A and X appears exactly once in the third-letter position of the example words, and in each case those that are *odd*-numbered in A1Z26 appear in the Trimpar Word list, while those that are *even*-numbered appear in the exceptions...
>
>  *Trimpar Words:*
>  PH**A**NTOM (A=1)
>  TA**C**ITLY (C=3)
>  QU**E**LLED (E=5)
>  LE**G**IBLE (G=7)
>  UT**I**LISE (I=9)
>  LI**K**ABLE (K=11)
>  LI**M**ITED (M=13)
>  PR**O**VIDE (O=15)
>  RE**Q**UIRE (Q=17)
>  AN**S**WERS (S=19)
>  EL**U**SORY (U=21)
>  UN**W**EAVE (W=23)
>
>  *Not Trimpar Words:*
>  UN**B**LIND (B=2)
>  AU**D**ITOR (D=4)
>  OF**F**HAND (F=6)
>  EC**H**ELON (H=8)
>  AD**J**USTS (J=10)
>  AL**L**UDES (L=12)
>  CO**N**VEYS (N=14)
>  IM**P**OSES (P=16)
>  PA**R**TAKE (R=18)
>  OU**T**LAYS (T=20)
>  RE**V**IVED (V=22)
>  TE**X**TUAL (X=24)

This makes perfect sense of Hint 2:

> *you may just agree*
>  *just see it in three*
>
>  'see it in three' = look at the **third letter**...
>
>  *if you can't see the truth*
>  *just take it in two*
>
>  'take it in two'= **divide it by two**.

This also fits with the choice of name for these words...

> 'Trimpar' is a blending of 2 words - 'TRI' and 'IMPAR':
>
>  - **TRI** is the common prefix meaning 'three' (e.g. tricycle, trisect, triceratops...);
>  - **IMPAR** is a word in many Romance languages (e.g. Spanish) which means *odd* (thanks to @GabrielG for pointing this out in comments).

Comment: In Romance languages, 'par' (or a variation) means 'even', and 'impar' means 'odd'; therefore, 'trimpar' is a portmanteau of 'tri' and 'impar'.

Comment: @GabrielG Oh, well done there! This was knowledge I didn't have. Thanks for pushing me over the finish line :)

Comment: Good job! Someone finally got it! :D

Comment: p.s. "impar" is also English - old middle English: "ORIGIN OF IMPAR
1375–1425 for earlier noun sense “odd number,” 1525–35 for current sense; late Middle English < Latin impār unequal. 

In today's English, it means "azygous" or "unpaired" which is still derivative of "odd number". Azygous means "not being one of a pair; single", as in, an even number is a pair of two of the same number, whereas an odd number is not one of a pair of the same numbers, as it is single in itself.

Comment: @Riddler Ah, that's news to me! I was so focussed on expecting the title to cleave cleanly in two I didn't spot the overlap and wouldn't have spotted this extra definition...